# C# .NET Process Runs in a Deadlock until Terminated

Tags: c#, cmd

For some reason, my Process object does not exit on its own and runs indefinitely until the timeout has been reached (in this case 60s).

I know that the cmd line execution has already done its job, however, I never get the Process has exited event

Any ideas why this happens?

```
Process cmd = new Process();

List<string> outputStreamMessages = new List<string>();

List<string> errorStreamMessages = new List<string>();

cmd.ErrorDataReceived += new DataReceivedEventHandler((sender,e) => {
    errorStreamMessages.Add(e.Data);
});

cmd.OutputDataReceived += new DataReceivedEventHandler((sender, e) => {
    outputStreamMessages.Add(e.Data);
});

cmd.Exited += new EventHandler((sender, e) => {
    Console.Writeline($"Exited!");
});

cmd.StartInfo = new ProcessStartInfo()
{
    FileName = "cmd.exe",
    RedirectStandardInput = true,
    RedirectStandardOutput = true,
    RedirectStandardError = true,
    CreateNoWindow = true,
    UseShellExecute = false
};

if (cmd.Start())
{
    cmd.StandardInput.WriteLine("<DUMMY CMD LINE>");

    cmd.BeginOutputReadLine();

    cmd.BeginErrorReadLine();
}
else
{
    throw new Exception($"Cmd Line Process was unable to start");
}

if (!cmd.WaitForExit(60000))
{
    if (cmd.Responding)
    {
        cmd.Close();
    }
    else
    {
        cmd.Kill();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure why you would expect the cmd process to exit. Inputting a command to the process will not cause the process itself to exit once the command has finished executing

I'm not sure what you mean by "my application runs in a loop" since the example does not contain any loops.

You would typically start a process to do whatever it is you want to do directly, rather than starting a command prompt and asking it to do things. Another alternative might be to use the powershell command prompt. It seem to accept commands as startup parameters, exiting the prompt when the command has completed.

Comment: Hi @JonasH, maybe I'm looking at this from the wrong perspective. I was expecting the process to exit once the cmd line execution would finish. Looks like I was wrong. I assume I need to manually close the process after the cmd line execution is complete.

Comment: Also edited the question to make it more simple/direct

Comment: @shoodaks If you start cmd.exe in windows and run a command, does the process close when the command has executed?

Comment: Hi @JonasH, yes

Comment: @shoodaks That is not a behavior I have ever seen. If I start cmd.exe and run ipconfig, the window and process for the command prompt stay open. Sure, ipconfig automatically closes, but not the command prompt.